# How to add the product name to the product details div

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I want to add the product name in the top of the right div in the propduct page.

[image]
Here is my template path enabled:
[image]

Here is my custom theme catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="fasony-custom-block" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">fasony-custom-block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="fasony-sidebar-products2" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">fasony-sidebar-products2</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="fasony-sidebar-banner" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">fasony-banner-sidebar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: By default it always show there, where title is coming right now ?

Comment: now title is in the top of the page, I think it due to the new theme Im using

Comment: are you fimiliar with layout system of magento ? just asking to know you are making changes in right file. check your theme Magento_Catalog/lahout/default.xml or catalog_product_view.xml file

Comment: hmm, i just looked at the fasony demo page: the product name should by default be exactly at the position where you want it to be. like here: http://demo4coder.com/fasony/ariel-roll-sleeve-sweatshirt-women.html

Comment: Thank you so much, my bad, I hided it long time ago (display: none) because it was displayed twice in the page, but with your code I put it in the right desired place. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new file in your theme

```
<magento-root>/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

in that file you can move the "page.main.title", which is the product name. e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

This should move the product name / page title above everything else inside the "product.info.main"-container

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: did you flush your page cache and static content?

Comment: yes, twice :) but didn't work

Comment: yeah, i see in your comments above that you use a custom theme. is there already the catalog_product_view.xml file present? if so, you should probably update your question and post the content of the mentioned file

Comment: Danke scho:n, Liebe gruSe aus Berlin ;)